# Bars not aligned with X-Axis ticks in CPTBarPlot of Core Plot

Tags: cocoa, core-plot

I have a problem with CPTBarPlot in Core Plot on Cocoa.
Namely, I cannot achieve to control step width of bars. X-Axis ticks are set normally as integer from 1 to infinite and drawing Scatter Plot on it works.

However, when bar plot is drawn, only first columns starts (with proper offset, of course) on first tick. Second is a bit further form its tick, so is third and all others as shown on screenshot:

[image]

I haven't found any property to control this, however, I found that data source method

```
-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
```

Behaves differently than when I draw Scatter Plot. namely, it enumerates only integer 3, which is CPTBarPlotBindingBarTips and doesn't enumerate any other constant, I am especially bothered with absence of CPTBarPlotBindingBarLocations.

If I start VerticalBarChart from Plot Gallery mac demo project I've checked and seen that same method enumerates 3,4 and 2 constants in same order.

I am using Core Plot 0.9 namely, I believe the same as in this demo. Still...

How to solve this?

Here is the complete code for labels and ticks on X axis;

```
    x.labelRotation = M_PI/4;
    x.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
    x.labelOffset = 0.0;

    CPTMutableTextStyle *labelStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
    labelStyle.fontSize = 9.0;
    x.labelTextStyle = labelStyle;

//    NSMutableArray *dateArray = [dataSeries objectAtIndex:0];
    NSMutableArray *customTickLocations = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSMutableArray *xAxisLabels = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (int i=0;i<[dataSeries count];i++) {

        [customTickLocations addObject:[NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:i+1]];
        [xAxisLabels addObject:[dataSeries objectAtIndex:i]];

    }

    //    [customTickLocations addObject:[NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:[dateArray count]]];

    NSUInteger labelLocation = 0;
    NSMutableArray *customLabels = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[xAxisLabels count]];
    for (NSNumber *tickLocation in customTickLocations) {
        CPTAxisLabel *newLabel = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithText: [xAxisLabels objectAtIndex:labelLocation++] textStyle:x.labelTextStyle];
        newLabel.tickLocation = [tickLocation decimalValue];
        newLabel.offset = x.labelOffset + x.majorTickLength;
        newLabel.rotation = M_PI/4;
        [customLabels addObject:newLabel];
        [newLabel release];
    }

    [x setMajorTickLocations:[NSSet setWithArray:customTickLocations]];

    x.axisLabels =  [NSSet setWithArray:customLabels];
```

I have to add that same ticks are being used when scatter plot is drawn on same plot space and it matches perfectly....

Answer (score 2):

The `field` parameter will be one of the members of this enum:

```
typedef enum _CPTBarPlotField {
    CPTBarPlotFieldBarLocation = 2, ///< Bar location on independent coordinate axis.
    CPTBarPlotFieldBarTip      = 3, ///< Bar tip value.
    CPTBarPlotFieldBarBase     = 4  ///< Bar base (used only if barBasesVary is YES).
} CPTBarPlotField;
```

If the plot's `plotRange` property is nil (the default), the plot will ask the datasource for locations and tips for each bar. If `barBasesVary` == YES, it will also ask for base values for each bar.

Comment: Sorry for late answer. What you have written here works. If barBasesVary is not yes, then only CPTBarPlotFieldBarTip is being iterated by delegate and not other two enums. However, implementing this does not solve the problem of bar step offset...Thanks anyway.

Comment: Your bar locations and major tick location don't line up. The solution will depend on which axis labeling policy you're using and how your datasource computes the bar locations. Post your plot setup and datasource code so we can offer more specific suggestions on how to fix it.

Comment: I have added the code, sorry. Take care of the fact that the sam code matches for scatter plot with same data perfectly.

Comment: That code works fine. Make sure your datasource is returning the index value for the bar location. Are your plot and axis using the same plot space? If not, make sure the xRanges are the same.

Comment: Plot and axis use the same plot space. I might also say, that if you don't add plot space neither to axis (both, x and y) and to graph, nothing is different... I believe the is a bug here..

Comment: As I can see from the code, CPTBarPlotFieldBarLocation = 2 is still not enumerated. I do not know, how to control this or how am I preventing this...

Comment: The only way to prevent the datasource from requesting CPTBarPlotFieldBarLocation is to set the bar plot's plotRange property. It defaults to nil, which tells the plot that it needs to ask the datasource for the locations.